# AuthorizationPolicy configuration issue: JWT authentication not working within specified namespace

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway, kubernetes-security, istio-operator

I'm currently facing an issue with the Istio AuthorizationPolicy configuration for JWT authentication. Our goal is to enable JWT authentication for traffic originating from outside the namespace, while allowing requests within the namespace to proceed without authentication.

Here is the relevant configuration:

```
 - List item

apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: auth-policy
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        requestPrincipals:
        - '*'
    - source:
        notNamespaces:
        - <namespace>
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      <key>: <value>


apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: "RequestAuthentication"
metadata:
  name: jwt
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      <key>: <value>
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "<issuer>"
    jwksUri: "<jwksUri>"
    fromHeaders:
    - name: x-jwt-assertion
      prefix: "Bearer "
```

The problem we're encountering is that requests within the specified namespace are also requiring authentication, despite using the notNamespaces field in the AuthorizationPolicy. We expected that requests within the namespace would be exempt from authentication.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into the correct configuration to achieve our desired behavior, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you in advance for your help!

In the Istio AuthorizationPolicy configuration, we attempted to implement JWT authentication with the following rules:

All traffic originating from outside the namespace should require JWT authentication.
Requests within the specified namespace should be allowed without any authentication.
To achieve this, we used the notNamespaces field in the AuthorizationPolicy to specify the namespace for which authentication should be bypassed.

We expected that requests originating from within the specified namespace would not trigger the JWT authentication process and would be allowed to proceed without any authentication requirements.

However, despite our configuration, requests within the specified namespace are still being subjected to JWT authentication, which is not the desired behavior. We are seeking assistance in understanding and resolving this issue.

Comment: You are having problems with pod to pod networning from differnet namespace?

Comment: No, pod to pod with in the same namespace

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AND semantics in the `from` section. The way you've written it is as if having two separate rules which have the [OR semantics](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/security-issues/#make-sure-there-are-no-typos-in-the-policy-yaml-file).

Remove the `-` to make it AND:

```
  - from:
    - source:
        requestPrincipals:
        - '*'
      source:
        notNamespaces:
        - <namespace>
```